# Center of image always in the center of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, center

I was trying to create a **carousel** replicating the one as in https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/ Barca's website. It was pretty easy, though I can't wrap my head around, on how to **make the `background-image` be centered inside my div**, despite my divs size, which fluctuates.

Here is what I got so far.

```js
const one = document.getElementById('one')
const two = document.getElementById('two')
const three = document.getElementById('three')

one.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
  one.style.flex= " 1 0 50%";
  two.style.flex= " 1 0 25%";
  three.style.flex= " 1 0 25%";
  one.style.transition = '0.4s ease';
});

two.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
  one.style.flex= " 1 0 25%";
  two.style.flex= " 1 0 50%";
  three.style.flex= " 1 0 25%";
  two.style.transition = '0.4s ease';
});

three.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
  one.style.flex= " 1 0 25%";
  two.style.flex= " 1 0 25%";
  three.style.flex= " 1 0 50%";
  three.style.transition = '0.4s ease';
});
```

```css
.main-body{
  display: flex;
}

.column{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image:url("https://www.basketblog.gr/articleimages/LebronJames_April20212112121212.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:500px;
}

#one{
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}

#two{
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

#three{
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-body">
      <div class="column" id="one">
      </div>
      <div class="column" id="two">
      </div>
      <div class="column" id="three">
      </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

I know my code seems a little lazy, I just wanted it to work

Comment: You can use `background-position: center` to do so :|

Comment: Oh, so it was that easy xD, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `background-position` property to do so.

By giving `center` value for the same would fix the problem I guess.

Try `background-position: center`